# Responisve Textarea

Tags: html, css

Hello guys i am trying  to make my textarea responsive. But i have really no idea how to do that. I tryied it with `width 100%` and `max-width 600px`. My Container also has a width of 600px. With `width 100%`the textarea gets smaller then the the Container that also has 600px. With `max-width 600px` the box gets extremly small.
This is my Code:

```
<div class="container contact">
<textarea class="inputmessage"></textarea>
</div>
.inputmessage{
    float: left;
    border: 2px solid black;
    height: 150px;
    width: 600px;
}
.container{
    text-align: center;
    margin: auto;
}

.contact{
    width: 600px !Important;
}
```

Comment: try to remove the `float:left` and `width:100%`

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Make max width on container to 600 px; remove the float.
Check this fiddle.

```
.inputmessage{
    border: 2px solid black;
    height: 150px;
    width: 100%;
}
.container{
    text-align: center;
    margin: auto;
}

.contact{
    width: 100%!Important;
    max-width:600px;
}
```

https://jsfiddle.net/Lx89qtte/